# h:inputFile and h:commandButton - NullPointerException

Tags: jsf-2, nullpointerexception, liferay, portlet

Hello I'm getting an error when uploading a file, even when my method in the bean is empty, I get the error.

Here is my JSF

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main-admin.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h:form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{userPictureUploadView.file}"/>
                    <h:commandButton value="Upload"
                                     action="#{userPictureUploadView.uploadProfilePicture}">
                    </h:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is the error I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter text is null
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.writeText(HtmlResponseWriter.java:949)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.writeText(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:298)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.renderkit.primefaces.internal.PrimeFacesInlineScript.encodeBegin(PrimeFacesInlineScript.java:51)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.renderkit.html_basic.internal.BodyRendererBridgeImpl.encodeBegin(BodyRendererBridgeImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:865)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1854)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
    at javax.faces.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.renderView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:146)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
    at com.liferay.faces.bridge.application.internal.ViewHandlerCompatImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerCompatImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    ... 223 more
```

I don't know why I'm getting an exception, it seems the error is fired after the method is executed, like in a reload.

All of this is in a portlet I made in Liferay.

More information:

- I'm using these versions of Liferay.faces.bridge
  'com.liferay.faces:com.liferay.faces.bridge.impl:4.0.0'
  'com.liferay.faces:com.liferay.faces.bridge.ext:5.0.0'

Comment: Your issue is due to a bug in Liferay Faces Bridge (Impl): [FACES-3031](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/).

Comment: Kyle is correct.  Your issue is caused by [FACES-3031](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/FACES-3031).

Comment: 1. Which version of Liferay are you using?

Comment: 2. Did you start your portlet by [using one of the archetypes](http://liferayfaces.org/) here?

Comment: Liferay 7.0 @Vernon

Comment: @Farid Ok, try [these dependencies](https://gist.github.com/vsingleton/aeb0bee10a6f1e39df643f4c66e2f812) and the error should go away.

Answer (score 1):

The solution will be to use ajax or an uploadListener

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="control-label">#{res['userProfilePictureUpload.profilePicture']}</div>
                            <p:fileUpload fileUploadListener="#{userPictureUploadView.handleFileUpload}" mode="advanced" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(png)$/" auto="true" previewWidth="0" label="#{res['userProfilePictureUpload.upload']}" oncomplete="location.reload();"/>
                        </div>
```